# Can't use the rows being retrieved from my database to build <li> items

Tags: jquery, ajax, sqlite, express

```
app.get('/api/getTransactions/', function(req, res){
  console.log("GET: Transactions");

  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM balance;';
  db.all(sql, [], function(err, rows){
        var result = {};
    if(err){
      res.status(404);
      result["error"] = err.message;
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
        res.json(rows);
    }
  });
});


function createTL() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/getTransactions/",
    data: {}
  }).done(function(rows){
    console.log("Request to fetch transactions");
    if("error" in rows){
      console.log(rows["error"]);
    } else {
      $(".tl").html('');
      var tList = '';
      console.log("Got Here");
      console.log(rows.length);
      for(var i=0; i++; i < rows.length){
        console.log("data");
        tList += '<li>Transaction: ' + rows[i].id + ' - ' + rows[i].text + ' - $' + rows[i].amount + '</li>';
        console.log(rows[i].id + " - " + rows[i].text + " - " + rows[i].amount);
      }
      $(".tl").html(tList);
    }
  });
}
```

There is no problem connecting to the database, and I can get the number of entries being retrieved from rows.length, but I can't figure out why I can't translate the rows into li elements.  Also, the first function is from the express app file, while the second function createTL() is from a static_files directory.

**UPDATE:** I got it working by altering the way the data was being sent and received, this is the working code.

```
app.get('/api/getTransactions/', function(req, res){
    var transactions = [];
  console.log("GET: Transactions");

  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM balance;';
  db.all(sql, [], function(err, rows){
        var result = {};
    if(err){
      res.status(404);
      result["error"] = err.message;
            res.json(result);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    } else {
      rows.forEach((row) => {
                transactions.push(row);
      });
            res.json(transactions);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(transactions));
    }
  });
});

function createTL() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/getTransactions/",
    data: {}
  }).done(function(rows){
    console.log("Request to fetch transactions");
    if("error" in rows){
      console.log(rows["error"]);
    } else {
      $("#tl").html('')
      var tList = '';
      for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
        tList += '<li>ID: ' + JSON.stringify(rows[i]["id"]) + ' - ' + JSON.stringify(rows[i]["text"]) + '- $' + JSON.stringify(rows[i]["amount"]) + '</li>';
      }
      $("#tl").html(tList);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any output at all that you can post or is the console.log empty?

Comment: `(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {id: 60, amount: 1900, text: "Bank Balance"}

1: {id: 62, amount: 65, text: "Refund"}

2: {id: 64, amount: -63, text: "Groceries"}

3: {id: 65, amount: -103.51, text: "Stock Loss"}

4: {id: 66, amount: 35.72, text: "Dividend"}

length: 5

__proto__: Array(0)
`
That's what I get when I console.log(rows)

Answer (score 0):

Check your console for errors or your html source for anything that might be rendered, perhaps incorrectly. This is based off your work and run's on jsfiddle:

```
<ul class="tl">

</ul>
```

JS

```
var rows = [
{id: 62, amount: 65, text: "Refund"},
{id: 64, amount: -63, text: "Groceries"},
{id: 65, amount: -103.51, text: "Stock Loss"},
{id: 66, amount: 35.72, text: "Dividend"} 
];

var $tList = $('.tl');
var tList = '';

for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
        tList += '<li>Transaction: ' + rows[i].id + ' - ' + rows[i].text + ' - $' + rows[i].amount + '</li>';
}

$tList.html(tList);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxLvbse0/

Comment: I managed to fix it by altering how the data was being sent from the express app to the jquery functions.  It took some playing around but the data is being delivered properly now, thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: @BrendanAnthonyMacLean you should post your solution then

Comment: I did, but I posted it as an update originally, I just reposted my new code as a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I got it working by altering the way the data was being sent and received, this is the working code.

```
app.get('/api/getTransactions/', function(req, res){
    var transactions = [];
  console.log("GET: Transactions");

  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM balance;';
  db.all(sql, [], function(err, rows){
        var result = {};
    if(err){
      res.status(404);
      result["error"] = err.message;
            res.json(result);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    } else {
      rows.forEach((row) => {
                transactions.push(row);
      });
            res.json(transactions);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(transactions));
    }
  });
});

function createTL() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/getTransactions/",
    data: {}
  }).done(function(rows){
    console.log("Request to fetch transactions");
    if("error" in rows){
      console.log(rows["error"]);
    } else {
      $("#tl").html('')
      var tList = '';
      for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
        tList += '<li>ID: ' + JSON.stringify(rows[i]["id"]) + ' - ' + JSON.stringify(rows[i]["text"]) + '- $' + JSON.stringify(rows[i]["amount"]) + '</li>';
      }
      $("#tl").html(tList);
    }
  });
}
```